# Linux kernel version suffix + CONFIG_LOCALVERSION

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

On system start up I currently see Linux 4.0.0-rc6yy and 4.0.0-rc6yy.old from the bootloader menu. I'm not certain where they came from. I suspect "yy" is arbitrary but can someone explain the ".old" suffix?

Also can someone explain what CONFIG_LOCALVERSION and CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO is from .config? I've looked them up but am still unclear about their use. Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are installing your kernel the responsible script is copying `kernel image` and `initramfs` into your `/boot` directory.
If a previous kernel image with the same name already exist, it is renamed by appending .old to its name.

`CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`:

> Append an extra string to the end of your kernel version. 
>      This will show up when you type uname, for example.
>      The string you set here will be appended after the contents of 
>      any files with a filename matching localversion* in your
>      object and source tree, in that order.  Your total string can
>      be a maximum of 64 characters.

That means if you want you can give a special version number or name to your customized kernel. If you type "-MyNewKernel" your kernel should look: `Linux 4.0.0-MyNewKernel`.

`CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO`:

> This will try to automatically determine if the current tree is a
>   release tree by looking for git tags that belong to the current
>   top of tree revision.
>   A string of the format -gxxxxxxxx will be added to the localversion
>   appended after any matching localversion<sup>1</sup> files, and after the value set in CONFIG_LOCALVERSION.
>
> <sup>1</sup> (The actual string used here is the first eight characters   produced by running the command:
>
> `$ git rev-parse --verify HEAD`
>
> which is done within the script "scripts/setlocalversion".)

That means if it is enabled the unique SCM (source control management) tag reported by  setlocalversion (or .scmversion) is appended to the kernel version, if it exists. For example if a git tree is found, the revision number will be appended if it exists. The result could look: `Linux 4.0.0-MyNewKernel-ga2cfc42`. For mores info you could check in your source tree scipts/setlocalversion.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think it's necessarily the first eight characters. I've just hit a situation where it was 11 characters. My guess is that the number of characters is at least 8 but will include as many characters as needed in order to be unique. It seems it's actually `git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD`.

Comment: quite right! i  thought the script was ignoring my config but it doesn't, when there's a tag the script takes the tag and not the hash, makes sence when u thin about it... :-)