# How can I change the OS version output?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, java, gentoo

My `uname -r` (and as is my real problem, Java system property os.version) returns a version number that has dashes in it.  It looks like: 5.9.12-gentoo-blah-blah.

This breaks an app I'm using which doesn't like the dashes in the version number (it expects just a number, no dashes allowed).

How can I change the version number of my operating system?  I just want to return the kernel version and don't worry about the rest.

Comment: Well you cannot do it easily. One option is to recompile the kernel or spoof the uname output. You are looking for a solution in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Alex: I can't modify the server I want to connect to, so I have to change something about my system.  And it dislikes the dashes in the OS version.  Recompiling the kernel won't help if I don't change anything - where does it get the version from?

Comment: Aha, so now it's related to a remote server. https://askubuntu.com/a/724421 this is how uname pulls kernel related information

Comment: *This breaks an app I'm using which doesn't like the dashes in the version number (it expects just a number, no dashes allowed).* That app is the problem, so I'd go ahead and fix the app. You're also running it, it seems, so you can basically preload and modify system libraries. Either you patch  `os.version`, or you patch that application. I'd have a clear favourite.

Comment: @MarcusMüller:okay, how do I patch a java app which I don't have the source code to and only the class files which I decompiled to find the problem?

Comment: as said, through preloading

Comment: LD_PRELOAD isn't going to work because the java executable isn't dynamically linked.  So you are back to somehow patching the Java application directly.  Is there a Java equivalent of LD_PRELOAD?  And if so could you write that as an answer?

Comment: Try writing a custom `uname`, put it in a special folder, and alter `PATH` prior to invoking just this app. Does it detect the name via shellout or a different way? You can run it under `strace` to figure that out. If it is getting this information a different way, you might be able to use namespaces to change that just for that application.

Comment: @binki: Java doesn't call `uname` executable, it uses the uname(2) system call.  (Found this using your suggestion of `strace`.  I don't care if I change my OS version system wide, I just need to know how to do it at all, not just for this one application.

Comment: @dave Well, if you’re willing to rebuild the kernel, see [`CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194205). You probably did not set this manually, but using [`genkernel` which only has `--kernel-append-localversion`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Genkernel#Options_acting_on_user_interactivity) which does not let you remove the `-gentoo`. So you can just [not use `genkernel`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Configuration) to avoid that and have control over the `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`.

Comment: But people are right when they say that the package is broken. The Java package is parsing the version string in a way which will break almost everywhere. Also, it is a Java package—why is it even checking the kernel version? The developers need to fix that. However, as people said, you can just use `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept its call to `uname(2)` once you figure out how `java` resolves that through glibc and then you can fool just `java` about the kernel version.

Comment: @dave I hacked up the `LD_PRELOAD` approach for fun: https://github.com/binki/binki-fool-java-os-version

Comment: @binki: I'll have a test of your `LD_PRELOAD` when I have hyphens back in my OS Version (I've rebuilt now without them).  I thought that trick only worked for dynamic executables and now I'm going to have to look up how it works (if I can't figure it out look out for another Question!)

Comment: You can override system calls in a statically linked executable with `ptrace`. It's a bit more complicated than `LD_PRELOAD`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426561/how-to-use-ptrace2-to-change-behaviour-of-syscalls, https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/06/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS release is returned from the kernel by the `uname` system call (`man 2 uname` for limited information about it).  The information can also be found under `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`.  That file is read-only and there's no way to change the OS release of a kernel after it has been built.

The OS release is set in the `Makefile` of the kernel.  The first 4 lines are:

```
VERSION =
PATCHLEVEL =
SUBLEVEL =
EXTRAVERSION =
```

It's also possible that extra information is added during the build if you build from a version control repository.

The kernel from Gentoo adds an EXTRAVERSION which has dashes in it.  Before building the kernel modify the `Makefile` to set the version to what you want.

Comment: For the record, see `setarch --uname-2.6 uname -rs` (doesn't change the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`, and doesn't remove those `-`s though).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be using LD_PRELOAD to intercept the uname system call. I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dnschneid/5c88a1802868c1be74d4debb5627c8c7) doing this.

Comment: binki already [provided a similar approach in the comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685313/how-can-i-change-the-os-version-output#comment1295113_685313)

Answer (score -3):

I hope it help:

Create bash file, e.g my_uname.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REPLACE_ON="~"
flag=$1
os_uname=$(/usr/bin/uname $flag)
pat="(a|r)"
if [[ "$flag" =~ $pat ]]; then
    echo $os_uname | sed "s/-/$REPLACE_ON/g"
else
    /usr/bin/uname $flag
fi
```

Watch your PATH variable for new script place

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/lib/llvm/13/bin
```

Set execution flag, and copy shell-script to the search PATH

```
chmod +x my_uname.sh
cp my_uname.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

After that create alias:

```
alias uname=my_uname.sh
```

Also you can put alias in .bashrc or .bash_profile

Comment: Except most programs don't call `uname` but use the syscall interface to get the information displayed there.  And even if they did then the alias only overrides `uname` when called from a shell where aliases are replaced and not from a program that calls `uname`

Answer (score -5):

If you just need the output of `uname -r` without the dashes and feed that as input to another process, then I would use `sed`:

```
uname -r | sed 's/-//g'
```

EDIT: if you think this answer is not useful, please explain why, so I can learn from your answer. We're all here to learn, not just to bash (if you pardon the pun).

Comment: As mentioned in my question the problem is the OS version as returned by the OS (specifically to Java, but more generally to uname).

Comment: Thanks. So, why not use ´sed´ to just return the version number using a regular expression? Get rid of all characters except numbers and dots. Unless you cannot use an external command in-between the output of ´uname -r´ and the app, in which case I misread your initial question.

Comment: I don't run `uname -r`, I run an app which gets the OS version information, the same information returned by `uname -r`.  I need that to be different inside the app.  So I want to change *my* environment to return a different version string.

Comment: Gotcha! Apologies, learning every day...